# Sort group members and aggregate with navigation function

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to group the table below, on columns `id` and `due_month`:

| id | created_at | due_month | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-02-05 | 2021-02 | paused |
| 1 | 2021-01-31 | 2021-02 | normal |
| 1 | 2021-01-15 | 2021-01 | normal |
| 2 | 2021-03-18 | 2021-03 | normal |
| 2 | 2021-03-07 | 2021-03 | paused |
| 2 | 2021-03-31 | 2021-08 | normal |

then within each group, sort the members on `created_at` in ascending order, and finally pick the last item's `status` value with latest `created_at` date (assumes that `created_at` never repeat on records with the same `id`).

Hence the output will look like this:

| id | due_month | status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01 | normal |
| 1 | 2021-02 | paused |
| 2 | 2021-03 | normal |
| 2 | 2021-08 | normal |

I tried out query like this but it didn't work (syntax error):

```
SELECT
  `id`,
  `due_month`,
  LAST_VALUE(`status`) OVER (ORDER BY `created_at`) AS `status`
FROM `some_table`
GROUP BY
  `id`,
  `due_month`
;
```

Also I know it's possible to join information like `` MAX(`created_at`) AS latest `` to the original table, then filter by `WHERE created_at = latest` to get what's needed, but that doesn't look very efficient.

Any better ideas for writing down this type of logics in BigQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select id, due_month, status
from your_table
where true 
qualify 1 = row_number() over win
window win as (partition by id, due_month order by created_at desc)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: glad it worked for you. consider also voting up he answer if it helped!